# R Shiny - plotOutput inline and size arguments prevents renderPlot from being entered

Tags: r, shiny

I've written an R shiny app before where a plot only displayed after a button was clicked. For some weird reason I cannot get the following code to enter the `renderPlot` function after a button click (i.e. `browser()` is never reached when clicking the button) and I'm stumped. Please be my second pair of eyes, I'm sure I'm missing something trivial.

The `observe` function works fine and updates the `selectizeInput` like I want. Importing of the csv also works fine and I can also use `DT::renderDataTable` to display it.

You can use [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3eRv-4znU32UEpJbEozWV9wNW8/view?usp=sharing) as example data, though it shouldn't matter since my code isn't plotting anything yet

Server

```
rm(list = ls())

library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(DT)
library(stringr)
library(zoo)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2) 

TAG_COL <- 1
TIME_COL <- 2
DATE_COL <- 3
ACTION_COL <- 4

HEADFIX_STR <- 'reward0'

shinyServer(function(input, output, clientData, session) {    
  inFile<-reactive({
    input$file1
    if(is.null(input$file1)){
      return(NULL)
    }
    else{
      inF<-read.csv(input$file1$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, quote=input$quote) 
      inF
    }
  })

  observe({ 
    if(!is.null(inFile)){
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "tagChooser",
                           'Choose Tags to plot',
                           choices = unique(inFile()[[TAG_COL]]))
    }
  })

  # Subset between start and end with bin column and selected mice
  subsetTable<-reactive({
    browser()
    # More code to come
  })

  # Plot histrogram of times between headfixes 
  # TODO: assumes all mice in same cage. Fix to make it work for a selection of mice from seperate cages
  output$plotHist<-renderPlot({
    input$goButton
    browser() # <-- Why is this browser() never reached after clicking the button?
    isolate({
        subsetTable()
        subsetHeadfixes<-subsetTable()
        # More code to come
      })
  })
})
```

ui

```
rm(list = ls())
# Immediately enter the browser/some function when an error occurs
# options(error = some funcion)

library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("MurphyLab"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv', 
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                         '.csv')),
      checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
      radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                   c(Comma=',',
                     Semicolon=';',
                     Tab='\t'),
                   ','),
      radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                   c(None='',
                     'Double Quote'='"',
                     'Single Quote'="'"),
                   '"'),
      selectizeInput('tagChooser', 'Choose Tags to plot', choices = c("data not loaded"), multiple = TRUE),
      textInput("abs_start","Insert start date and time. Format: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",value="2015-06-15 01:00:00"),
      textInput("abs_end","Insert end date and time. Format: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",value="2015-08-15 01:00:00"),
      textInput("binning", "Binning in seconds",value = 86400),
      actionButton("goButton", "Plot")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plotHist", inline = TRUE,width='auto',height='auto')
    )
  )
)
)
```

UPDATE:

So when I change the `plotOutput` call in `mainPanel` to `plotOutput("plotHist")` everything works as expected. I'm changing my question instead to: Why does this fix things? Also, having only `inline` set to FALSE does not fix things.

Documentation for [inline](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/plotOutput.html) states:

> use an inline (span()) or block container (div()) for the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation of [`renderPlot()`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderPlot.html) (I highlighted the relevent part below):

> `width`,`height`  The width/height of the rendered plot, in pixels; or 'auto' to use the offsetWidth/offsetHeight of the HTML element that is bound to this plot. You can also pass in a function that returns the width/height in pixels or 'auto'; in the body of the function you may reference reactive values and functions. **When rendering an inline plot, you must provide numeric values (in pixels) to both width and height.**